# Facing problems while installing Laravel v4.2 on windows 7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

I am facing problems while installing Laravel on windows 7.

I am using Xampp and installed composer, added the path in the system variable. But when I run "`composer install`", I found this problem...

> Composer could not find the config file
>   C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin To initialize a project, please
>   create a composer.json file as described in the
>   http://getcomposer.org/, "Getting started section"

I don't know what I have to do now. Please help. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You shouldn't be doing `composer install`, you should be doing `composer create-project laravel/laravel your-project-name --prefer-dist` per the documentation.

Comment: After running this command "composer create-project laravel/laravel your-project-name --prefer-dist", i run "composer install" from my project directory folder. But composer could not find the config file, why?

Comment: I also had that problem. I have reïnstalled the composer and did `composer update`. 
Do you have an specific error?

Comment: I also ran "composer update" command and again found the same result that "Invalid Argument Exception, Composer could not find the config file blablabla." i dont know where is my fault? @WQuaniran.

Comment: Do you have the original `composer.json` file in the directory?

Comment: original means? and which directory u r talking about? @WQuaniran

Comment: The Directory where your composer have to be

Comment: There is no composer.json file in my composer directory--C:\ProgramData\ComposerData\bin.@ WQuaniran

Answer (score 0):

Try `curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php` or `php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php` for a clean install.

If nothing works download [this](https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar).

You can download [Putty](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/x86/putty.exe) to run this commands.

(Make sure your XAMPP or whatever program you are using is running!)

Comment: There is no `curl` in Windows by default, so your first example will not work.

Comment: you can download http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/x86/putty.exe (putty)

Comment: @WQuaniran AFAIK during composer installation it is not required to run XAMPP or other similar programs.